# Yefat To'ar: Only for the Victors

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons, army-military-war, ki-teitzei

Why does the Torah allow for a יְפַת תֹּאַר only in the case of a victory?

Comment: Can you source that fact into the question?

Answer (score 3):

The **Meshech Chachmah** answers with a very simple Pshat. If they did not win, she was used as a bargaining chip in the hostage exchange that happens after the battle.